# How do I convert this list of dictionaries to a table or csv file?

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary, python-3.7

Can't convert Python dict to table and then export data to csv.

```
dict string: {"test_sheet": {"testheader": [{"2018-12-31": {"field1": 8482000000, "field2": 166731000000, "field3": 92128000000}}, {"2018-11-30": {"field1": 7579000000, "field2": 171652000000, "field3": 85967000000}}, {"2018-10-31": {"field1": 8053000000, "field2": 176130000000, "field3": 82718000000}}, {"2018-09-30": {"field1": 8544000000, "field2": 166258000000, "field3": 79239000000}}]}}

Format of table needed:
Report     Name       Date       Field1     Field2       Field3
test_sheet testheader 31.12.2018 8482000000 166731000000 92128000000
test_sheet testheader 30.11.2018 7579000000 171652000000 85967000000
test_sheet testheader 31.10.2018 8053000000 176130000000 82718000000
test_sheet testheader 30.09.2018 8544000000 166258000000 79239000000
```

Trying convert dict to csv with read_json

```
import pandas
data = {"test_sheet": {"testheader": [{"2018-12-31": {"field1": 8482000000, "field2": 166731000000, "field3": 92128000000}}, {"2018-11-30": {"field1": 7579000000, "field2": 171652000000, "field3": 85967000000}}, {"2018-10-31": {"field1": 8053000000, "field2": 176130000000, "field3": 82718000000}}, {"2018-09-30": {"field1": 8544000000, "field2": 166258000000, "field3": 79239000000}}]}}

pandas.read_json(json.dumps(data)).to_csv('testfile.csv')
```

But after export to csv all data saving in first row.

**New detailed input data :**

```
{"test_sheet": {"testheader": [ {"2018-12-31": {"field1": 8482000000, "field2": 166731000000, "field3": 92128000000}}, {"2018-11-30": {"field1": 7579000000, "field2": 171652000000, "field3": 85967000000, "field4": 6679000000, "field5": 159000000}}, {"2018-10-31": {"field1": 8053000000, "field2": 176130000000, "field3": 82718000000, "field4": 1218000000}}, {"2018-09-30": {"field1": 8544000000, "field2": 166258000000, "field3": 79239000000}}], "testheader1": [ {"2018-12-31": {"field1": 8482000000, "field2": 166731000000, "field3": 92128000000, "field4": 124000000}}, {"2018-11-30": {"field1": 7579000000, "field2": 171652000000, "field3": 85967000000, "field4": 44367000000, "field5": 582000000}}, {"2018-10-31": {"field1": 8053000000, "field2": 176130000000, "field3": 82718000000, "field4": 132500000, "field5": 15847000, "field6": 1982330000}}, {"2018-09-30": {"field1": 8544000000, "field2": 166258000000, "field3": 79239000000}}]}}
```

**Needed output format for this data:**

```
Report      Name        Date       FieldName FieldValue
test_sheet  testheader  31.12.2018  Field1  8482000000
test_sheet  testheader  31.12.2018  Field2  166731000000
test_sheet  testheader  31.12.2018  Field3  92128000000
test_sheet  testheader  30.11.2018  Field1  7579000000
test_sheet  testheader  30.11.2018  Field2  171652000000
test_sheet  testheader  30.11.2018  Field3  85967000000
test_sheet  testheader  30.11.2018  Field4  6679000000
test_sheet  testheader  30.11.2018  Field5  159000000
test_sheet  testheader  31.10.2018  Field1  8053000000
test_sheet  testheader  31.10.2018  Field2  176130000000
test_sheet  testheader  31.10.2018  Field3  82718000000
test_sheet  testheader  31.10.2018  Field4  1218000000
test_sheet  testheader  30.09.2018  Field1  8544000000
test_sheet  testheader  30.09.2018  Field2  166258000000
test_sheet  testheader  30.09.2018  Field3  79239000000
test_sheet  testheader1 31.12.2018  Field1  8482000000
test_sheet  testheader1 31.12.2018  Field2  166731000000
test_sheet  testheader1 31.12.2018  Field3  92128000000
test_sheet  testheader1 31.12.2018  Field4  124000000
test_sheet  testheader1 30.11.2018  Field1  7579000000
test_sheet  testheader1 30.11.2018  Field2  171652000000
test_sheet  testheader1 30.11.2018  Field3  85967000000
test_sheet  testheader1 30.11.2018  Field4  44367000000
test_sheet  testheader1 30.11.2018  Field5  582000000
test_sheet  testheader1 31.10.2018  Field1  8053000000
test_sheet  testheader1 31.10.2018  Field2  176130000000
test_sheet  testheader1 31.10.2018  Field3  82718000000
test_sheet  testheader1 31.10.2018  Field4  132500000
test_sheet  testheader1 31.10.2018  Field5  15847000
test_sheet  testheader1 31.10.2018  Field6  1982330000
test_sheet  testheader1 30.09.2018  Field1  8544000000
test_sheet  testheader1 30.09.2018  Field2  166258000000
test_sheet  testheader1 30.09.2018  Field3  79239000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data set is too custom to be used with some framework. This is a way to do it:

```
import csv

data = {"test_sheet": {"testheader": [{"2018-12-31": {"field1": 8482000000, "field2": 166731000000, "field3": 92128000000}}, {"2018-11-30": {"field1": 7579000000, "field2": 171652000000, "field3": 85967000000}}, {"2018-10-31": {"field1": 8053000000, "field2": 176130000000, "field3": 82718000000}}, {"2018-09-30": {"field1": 8544000000, "field2": 166258000000, "field3": 79239000000}}]}}
pf = open("out.csv", "w")
writer = csv.DictWriter(pf, fieldnames=["Report", "Name", "Date", "Field1", "Field2", "Field3"])

writer.writeheader()

for report, report_data in data.items():
    for name, name_data in report_data.items():
        for date_wrapper in name_data:
            date = list(date_wrapper.keys())[0]
            date_data = date_wrapper[date]
            writer.writerow({
                "Report": report,
                "Name": name,
                "Date": date,
                "Field1": date_data['field1'],
                "Field2": date_data['field2'],
                "Field3": date_data['field3']
            })

pf.close()
```

**UPDATE:** For the second version:

```
import csv

data = {"test_sheet": {"testheader": [ {"2018-12-31": {"field1": 8482000000, "field2": 166731000000, "field3": 92128000000}}, {"2018-11-30": {"field1": 7579000000, "field2": 171652000000, "field3": 85967000000, "field4": 6679000000, "field5": 159000000}}, {"2018-10-31": {"field1": 8053000000, "field2": 176130000000, "field3": 82718000000, "field4": 1218000000}}, {"2018-09-30": {"field1": 8544000000, "field2": 166258000000, "field3": 79239000000}}], "testheader1": [ {"2018-12-31": {"field1": 8482000000, "field2": 166731000000, "field3": 92128000000, "field4": 124000000}}, {"2018-11-30": {"field1": 7579000000, "field2": 171652000000, "field3": 85967000000, "field4": 44367000000, "field5": 582000000}}, {"2018-10-31": {"field1": 8053000000, "field2": 176130000000, "field3": 82718000000, "field4": 132500000, "field5": 15847000, "field6": 1982330000}}, {"2018-09-30": {"field1": 8544000000, "field2": 166258000000, "field3": 79239000000}}]}}
pf = open("out.csv", "w")
writer = csv.DictWriter(pf, fieldnames=["Report", "Name", "Date", "FieldName", "FieldValue"])

writer.writeheader()

for report, report_data in data.items():
    for name, name_data in report_data.items():
        for date_wrapper in name_data:
            date = list(date_wrapper.keys())[0]
            date_data = date_wrapper[date]

            for field_name, field_value in date_data.items():
                writer.writerow({
                    "Report": report,
                    "Name": name,
                    "Date": date,
                    "FieldName": field_name,
                    "FieldValue": field_value
                })

pf.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what is needed, but in csv file blank rows alternate with data rows. Please, can u help to fix it?

Comment: @Игорь according to the dataset you provided in your question the CSV should have a continuous flow of rows. Is the data that you pass to the script any different from the one you provided in your question?

Comment: The data is the same. I just copied the code and looked into the out file.

Comment: Weird because when I look at it I don't see any blank lines. And you shouldn't be having any new blanklines because I'm not adding anything to the file after a writerow. I'm opening it as a text file and there is only one newline per row. Maybe try another CSV editor?

Comment: @Igor, make sure to mark the answer as correct if it helped you. It usually helps other users on stackoverflow to identify as experts in certain areas.

Comment: Excel and Notepad ++ open the file with blank rows, but the windows notepad opens the file correctly. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, Andrei. I understood that I had a little mistake in the output data structure. I'm add corrent input and new output data structure in first message. Can u please help me again?

Comment: Excellent, you helped me a lot. Andrei,thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your data format is quite nested. CSV doesn't handle nested structure very well.

The code you had provided will work - provided you pre-process your data a bit beforehand. 
Each of the rows can be accessed like: `data["test_sheet"]["test_header"][i]`
Access each row like this & add the first 2 columns to it.

Comment: Thanks for your help.